# Making a google sheet copy with a bounded script does not copy the script as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with a bound script as a template, and i am using it to copy it and generate a new file in other folders.

When I copy the template I expect that the copy does not only copy the sheet but the bound script as well. However, this is not the case. The copy has no bounded script and the user defined functions that I call within the copied sheet are not working, because well, they are not there!

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Leo

Comment: Please post the script you're using to make the copies.

Comment: If you make copies with Google Drive Tools the scripts get copied also.

Comment: The script is a methods makeCopy from the Drive API: makecopy("Name", Folder). However when I make a copy directly from the sheet, doing it by hand, it doesn't copy the Script either.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this script to copy a spreadsheet with code in it and the code was copied along with the file.  Is this close to what your doing?

```
function copyThisFile(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fileId=ss.getId();
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  file.makeCopy();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I'm doing, but neither making a copy manually or by code works

Comment: I'd try opening another spreadsheet file and try it there.  I've had problems which were resolved in that way.  I don't know the why. Don't forget to turn on the Drive API in resources.